# How do I display only the class name in doxygen class diagrams?

Tags: c#, documentation, uml, diagram, doxygen

Using doxygen and graphviz with my C# project, I can generate class diagrams in the documentation pages. These diagrams have the full class names and namespaces in them, e.g.

```
Acme.MyProduct.MyClasses.MyClass
```

Is it possible to configure doxygen to cut this down a bit to just the class name?

```
MyClass
```

The fully qualified paths make even simple diagrams rather wide and unwieldy. I'd like to minimize the need for horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect that you've already solved this as it is a year old, but an answer might be useful for anyone else searching for this (as I just did). You can use the "HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES" option. Setting it to YES (or checking it in the doxywizard GUI) will hide namespaces. From my doxygen file:

```
# If the HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES tag is set to NO (the default) then Doxygen 
# will show members with their full class and namespace scopes in the 
# documentation. If set to YES the scope will be hidden.

HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
```

Answer (score 3):

The **HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES** works great but only hides the scope in the class diagram but not the caller/callee graphs for each method.

To reduce the width of those diagrams to a readable size you can rename the scope using the input filter.  This will not remove the namespace but will reduce it to a more readable width.

For example to rename the namespace "COMPANY_NAMESPACE" to "sf" use:

```
# The INPUT_FILTER tag can be used to specify a program that doxygen should 
# invoke to filter for each input file. Doxygen will invoke the filter program 
# by executing (via popen()) the command <filter> <input-file>, where <filter> 
# is the value of the INPUT_FILTER tag, and <input-file> is the name of an 
# input file. Doxygen will then use the output that the filter program writes 
# to standard output.  If FILTER_PATTERNS is specified, this tag will be 
# ignored.

INPUT_FILTER           = "sed 's,COMPANY_NAMESPACE,sf,'"
```